# Clicking on a checkbox (hidden) in a dynamic web table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, html-table

[Screenshot of the Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTxVp.png)

In the following scenario, I want to click the checkbox (Class = hidden) in a web table, I am using the XPath to locate the checkbox, but when I perform the click operation it gives me a below error:

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click
> intercepted: Element <input class="hidden" name="id" readonly=""
> tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value=""> is not clickable at point (70,
> 216). Other element would receive the click: <label></label>

Code to click an element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/input")).click();
```

[**HTML code:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD6TR.png)

Comment: Error clearly says that, element in hidden status and you can't perform click operation on it. If you really need to click on this checkbox, make this checkbox to be displayed on UI and then click..

Comment: The checkbox is displayed in the application and I can select the checkbox manually, however, when I try to select the checkbox using selenium, I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot if possible? In HTML code, I can see the checkbox is read only i.e. its not possible to interact, but you said you are able to when we work manually..

Comment: @Sreenivasulu I have attached the screenshot above, please refer to it.

Comment: @shubam saxena After looking at screenshot what you attached, the checkbox what you selected is first row, But your xpath looking for 2nd row (/table/tbody/tr[2]). That means your xpath matches with 2nd record i.e. Rahul Prakash Prakash, not Shubham Saxena.. Can you check this once?

Comment: @Sreenivasulu I have attached the screenshot just to show you that I can select the checkbox manually. 
But when I automate this, weather I select the first row checkbox or the second row checkbox, it throws an error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input class="hidden" name="id" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value=""> is not clickable at point (70, 216). Other element would receive the click: <label></label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem resolved by clicking the checkbox using JavaScriptExecuter. Below code works:

```
public static void clickElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```